# Limit the size of text being echod from an array Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

In my CI application I am displaying text from array:

```
<?php echo $music[0]['title']?>
```

What is the easiest way to limit size of text I would either like to limit text in terms of characters or pixel size. I tried using CSS but it only works for actual text. Any help is appropriated.

Comment: _“I tried using CSS but it only works for actual text.”_ – and what you are trying to output is _not_ text …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    //IN CONTROLLER
    $this->load->helper('text');

    //In view file
    //For Word Limiter use word_limiter($str, $limit = 100, $end_char = '&#8230;');
    //FOr Character character_limiter($str, $n = 500, $end_char = '&#8230;');
    Example:
    <?php echo word_limiter($music[0]['title'],30); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple truncate function would work, as described here: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/truncate/#.UW9GjLW9uSo

```
// Original PHP code by Chirp Internet: www.chirp.com.au
// Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header.
function myTruncate($string, $limit, $break=".", $pad="...")
{
  // return with no change if string is shorter than $limit
  if(strlen($string) <= $limit) return $string;

  // is $break present between $limit and the end of the string?
  if(false !== ($breakpoint = strpos($string, $break, $limit))) {
    if($breakpoint < strlen($string) - 1) {
      $string = substr($string, 0, $breakpoint) . $pad;
    }
  }

  return $string;
}
```

Then your code would be (if you wanted to display at most 30 characters):

```
<?php echo myTruncate($music[0]['title'], 30) ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and just to clarify code for function would be inside controller?

Comment: You could put it in your controller, but it would be better to put it in a helper if your going to be using it in multiple controllers/views.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer. I tried using function as suggested but the size of the text doesn't change?

Comment: As Jeemusu said, a helper would be the right place for it.  I don't believe it will be available to the view file if you put it in the controller.

Comment: doesn't work even with helper, but thanks anyway. I even tried placing whole function inside the view just for test.

Comment: Yeah that should definitely work.  Looking at the function, and depending on your data, you may need to specify the 3rd parameter as a  `" "` or something else, since it looks like the default behavior is to keep going until it finds a period.

Comment: That will mess up things quite nicely for text encodings using more than one byte to store characters, like UTF-8. You should at least use the mbstring functions for this.